# How to change python3 path pointer?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, python3, paths

I am using *Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS* with **python version 3.9.5** installed.

When I type `which python` in the terminal, it shows `/usr/bin/python` which is the default path for *python2* (2.7 in my case).
But when I type `which python3`, it shows `/usr/local/bin/python3`, not the usual default path (`/usr/bin/python3`) for python3.

I've checked my `/usr/bin` folder and I did notice that there are files named python3 and python3.9. I just want my python3 path variable to point to the location `/usr/bin/python3` or `/usr/bin/python3.9`. What steps should I take to do that?

P.S., **I don't want to set default python to python3**, of which instructions I found in the ask-ubuntu forum and also in many articles after some googling. I just want to set my python3 path to `/usr/bin/python3` or `/usr/bin/python3.9`

Comment: DO NOT change default python3, My 20.04 shows `ls -l /usr/bin/python*
` : `/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
` Ubuntu uses that version and change of version will break Ubuntu. Years ago only fix was total reinstall. Now it may be repaired if you have live installer and can chroot back into system to reset to correct python. You can install as many other python versions as you want but have to specifically refer to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as a custom `python3` is installed in `/usr/local/bin/`, it will show up as the default `python3` executable. why? Because by default, `/usr/local/bin/` is listed earlier in the search path then `/usr/bin`. This way, your custom executables have priority over these installed by the system.

To make the system find `/usr/bin/python3` first, you must move out `/usr/local/bin/python3`. The alternative would be to ticker with your PATH, moving `/usr/local/bin` behind, but that would affect every other custom executable.

Thus, rename `/usr/local/bin/python3` to `/usr/local/bin/python3cust` or something. Then, you will be using the default python version.

On Ubuntu, you actually may not change the default python version. Python is extensively used in the operating system. Changing the version will likely break things.