# Problem updating snaps on 20.04

Tags: apt, gnome, snap, python3, alias

A few days ago I tried to change my default python3 path from `/usr/local/bin/python3` to `/usr/bin/python3` on my *Ubuntu 20.04 (Desktop Env => Gnome 3.36)* by -

1. creating a symlink to the desired path and
2. writing an alias (`alias python3='/usr/bin/python3'`) in .bashrc.

But neither of those worked and I think it did create some problems in my system. I couldn't figure out exactly what happened and deleted the alias from .bashrc then thinking it'd solve the problem but it didn't ([This is the question I asked and tried to execute the steps that were told in the reply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348089/how-to-change-python3-path-pointer)).

Now I am trying to update my snaps by running :

```
$ sudo snap refresh
```

But the problem is, it is not being updated although I have a stable internet connection.
The output that I am getting is as follows :

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "core" (11316) from channel "latest/stable" (invalid credentials)
```

I need guidance on which settings/packages to update/remove/modify in order to solve this problem.

Note: For extra information, I am also getting a Traceback message on tty shell saying :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/hwe-support-status", line 13, in <module>
      import apt
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-package/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
      import apt_pkg
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

My apt package is working fine though, didn't face any error while updating and upgrading my system by running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: Are you using the Unity desktop as suggested by the tag you added? Can you be more specific about that "change something"?  That will increase the chance that someone can provide a step by step guide.

Comment: if you did it in terminal, the commands you used will still be there in the history... open terminal and use the up arrow key to scroll back to what you typed.

Comment: Edit your question to add and update relevant information related to your question. Comments are not always read and may disappear.